# How do I reset a system's network settings to default?

Tags: centos, networking

I have a system currently connected through ethernet but it's network settings are not working at all so I have no connection to the internet. This system was basically cloned from a previous system so it has its network settings but on new hardware which is why the network is not working. Is there a way I can just reset or remove the network settings completely to a default state or make it so that I can remove the current network settings and tell the system to detect the new hardware? This is on Centos 8 by the way/

Comment: Are you running NetworkManager?

Comment: I ran service NetworkManager status and it tells me it is active and also that "NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL".

Comment: This might be a double of help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/637637/how-to-reset-network-manager-to-default

Comment: Are you just trying to make your cloned system's networking work, or are you looking for a general way to reset a system's network configuration after cloning it? Which NetworkManager tools are you familiar with/which tools are available to you (e.g. nmcli, nmtui, some graphical program)? Have you tried removing your current network connection(s) and creating a new one? (AFAIK there is no bullet-proof or "standard" way to reset a configuration - short of starting with a clean installation).

Answer (score 2):

The network interfaces configuration is saved under the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` directory, you can check it through:

```
ls /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg*
```

Keep the `ifcfg-lo` file and remove the others then set a new configuration for your network interfaces. Also, you can use `nmcli`  to delete the configured newtork:

```
nmcli connection delete id <connection name>
```